# Как скачать видеофайл, если он защищён от скачивания и буферизируется с подкачиванием?

Tags: javascript

Как скачать файл, если есть защита от скачивания и как таковой файл в браузер не грузится, а грузятся фрагменты, которые как-то расшифровываются и потом отрисовываются ?
Мне говорят, мол, всё, что отображается в браузере- можно скачать.... оно то да! только есть ли скрипт, который бы сшивал эти зашифрованные фрагменты, чтоб можно было скачать файл?
Всякие стандартные скрипты-расширения браузера из топ поиска по гуглу - такие задачи не берут.
Что можете порекомендовать?

Comment: можно ссылку на этот файл? ну или идентичный

Comment: любой видео плеер делает это